# How to convert a XML object file with a timespan node to a C# class in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, .net-standard

I have a .NET Standard library with a class

```
    public class RetryPolicy
    {    
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public TimeSpan TimeIncreasedBetweenRetries { get; set; }
    }
```

When deserialized via the method,

> System.Xml.Serialization.XMlSerializer Deserialize

, a different behaviour occurs depending on the Target Framework:

- When a DotNet Core version (3.1) is selected there is no issue.
- When a DotNet Framework version (4.7.2) is selected no conversion is made and we get a timespan of 0.

I tried to solve this issue by implementing a custom XmlElement type

```
public class RetryPolicy
{    
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    [XmlElement(typeof(XmlTimeSpan))]
    public TimeSpan TimeIncreaseBetweenDelayedRetries { get; set; }
}
```

Custom class

```
    /// <summary>
    /// XML timespan serialization helper class (used in XMLSerializerAttribute on TimeSpan properties)
    /// </summary>
    public class XmlTimeSpan
    {
        private TimeSpan _internalValue = TimeSpan.Zero;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public XmlTimeSpan()
            : this(TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public XmlTimeSpan(TimeSpan input)
        {
            _internalValue = input;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implicit operator
        /// </summary>
        public static implicit operator TimeSpan(XmlTimeSpan input)
        {
            return (input != null) ? input._internalValue : TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Alternative implicit operator
        /// </summary>
        public TimeSpan ToTimeSpan()
        {
            return _internalValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implicit operator
        /// </summary>
        public static implicit operator XmlTimeSpan(TimeSpan input)
        {
            return new XmlTimeSpan(input);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Alternative implicit operator
        /// </summary>
        public void FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan input)
        {
            this._internalValue = input;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The string value
        /// </summary>
        [XmlText]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return XmlConvert.ToString(_internalValue);
            }
            set
            {
                _internalValue = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

When this attribute is added I receive an error:

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
> error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
> error CS0012: The type 'System.ICloneable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
> error CS0012: The type 'System.Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

How can I make it possible a TimeSpan property in a class is successfully converted in a .NET standard library where both .NET Core and .NET frameworks should be able to use it?